# C Compiler and Linker section naming

Tags: c, gcc, linker, gnu, ld

I am using specific section to store my variables so they are contiguous in memory.
I would like to reference the memory area in which my variables are stored.

I have come across the usage of __start_XXX and __stop_XXX symbols provided by the linker, XXX being a section name.

I have been looking for a documentation regarding the definition of __start_ and __stop_ symbols.
Furthermore does the name of the section has an impact on it : section usually start with a dot ".mysection", a section starting with a dot seems to be handled different from those which don't. In which documentation is this defined ?

Additional question :
I am able to order the section in my linker file using sort.
How are the element under each section ordered ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

1. Documentation:

The position of the section is not related to the alphabetical order of the used section names.

Which tool-set you are using? In case of GCC this link will help you [Linker Scripts](https://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/ld_3.html)

2. Additional question:

The order of objects in the memory (linked binary) corresponds to the order of files given to the linker.